# Bootstrap-social button doesn't work on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using boostrap-social buttons in my Rails app. It works perfectly fine locally, but in production, on Heroku, button is displayed without Twitter icon. What can be the issue?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your javascript (check the Chrome console)?

Comment: Hello, yes - File not found: my app address/assets/application-8cd48e63f113a66865e92f9c1fac268c882bdf56078fa9701be9fe296a8457d8.css

Comment: So you may want to run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and push your public directory.

Comment: Thank you, I did it, but icon still doesn't show! what else can it be? I don't really get it, because after running command you mentioned, it creates exactly the same file it later says is missing

Comment: Did you install bootstrap-social the right way? Is bootstrap-social.css included in your CSS? When you _inspect_ the twitter icon, can you retrieve the file in which the _ban-twitter_ class is defined?